# is map of string with xx elements The given key does not identify an element in this collection value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have this in my tf file
`existing_alerting_sns_topic        =  "arn:aws:sns:${var.aws_region}:${module.account.id[“ab-cd”]}:cd-prod-${var.aws_region}-slack-notifier-infrastructure-alerts"`

but I don't have anything specified in my variable.tf yet. when I run the terraform plan I do see the below error. Do I need to specify anything like map(any) or map(list(string)) ??

````
│ 
│  existing_alerting_sns_topic        =  "arn:aws:sns:${var.aws_region}:${module.account.id[“ab-cd”]}:cd-prod-${var.aws_region}-slack-notifier-infrastructure-alerts"
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.account.id is map of string with 105 elements
│ 
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value```

Thanks!
````

Comment: What would happen if you do `module.account["ab-cd"].id`?

Comment: Also, we don't know what the module does, how it's invoked, so a lot of details are missing.

Answer (score 0):

It simply says that:

- the module `account`'s output `id` is a huge map of strings (105) but
- none of them is called `ab-cd`.

Maybe a typo in the outputs of the account module?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking into my question. I have figured out the error was about the case sensitive letters(ab-CD) I have mentioned for the account name in the line
`${module.account.id[“ab-cd”]}`
Thanks!